# Change SQL Server Data Source / Instance to be relative in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string

When we connect to a SQL Server database file, we use this syntax

```
string conString = "Data Source=MIRANDA-PC;Initial Catalog=Futebol do Rosa;Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
```

The problem with this approach is that it only works when the database is on my computer and when I go to another PC I have to change paths in the code manually. Is there a way to change this to a relative path that works in any computer?

Comment: Path? You mean the hostname in the Data-Source?

Comment: Set datasource to localhost?

Comment: Hard coding the details of the connectionstring inside your code is like hard coding path to files or resource on your disk. Don't do that. App.Config and ConnectionStrings section exist for a reason.

Comment: the other problem and or issue that you are causing yourself is hardcoding your connection string.. to prevent yourself from having to change code manually .. `Move the ConnectionString` to a .Config file.. here is a site that can show you how to easily configure your connection strings in your application [C# Database ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: Kenneth, how do I change it to localhost then? Yes it's the datasource of the database.

Comment: `localhost` is the `Literal word` that you type please move away from hard coding it's easier to change the value in one place `i.e app || web.config file` vs changing values in 100 different places 
if you don't have the time then just change it to this 
`string conString = "Data Source=localhost;` `MSDN Reference here` [How to Connect to SQL Server Database using SqlServerDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228094(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: do you have sql server Management Studio installed on your machine..

Comment: nevermind, instead of writing localhost, I tried LOCALHOST and it worked

Comment: shouldn't really matter.. perhaps you had a typo in your original lol

Comment: @MethodMan and Miranda Code: The actual preferred method is to use `(local)`, not `localhost`. Please see my answer for details. Though I definitely agree with moving the connection string to a config file :).

Comment: @KennethIto The actual preferred method is to use `(local)`, not `localhost`. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method for SQL Server to connect to the local/default instance is to use `(local)`, as in:

```
Data Source=(local)
```

This is documented on the MSDN page for [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx), which also states:

> When specifying a local instance, always use (local).

This is because `(local)` defaults to shared memory instead of a full TCP connection. That same MSDN page, also in the section for "Data Source ...", states:

> You can force the use of TCP instead of shared memory, either by prefixing **tcp:** to the server name in the connection string, or by using **localhost**.

But, that should be the default anyway if `Data Source` is not even specified. Hence, the following should work:

```
"Initial Catalog=Futebol do Rosa;Integrated Security=True"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you. If you are working in a desktop app, Move the ConnectionString to your settings file.

When your app can't find the server because it was renamed or moved, launch a winForm with the parameters like "server, user, password..." so, with these parameters update your ConnectionString in your settings.

[image: Connection]

In your app you can use the parameters in your settings in your connectionString

```
Friend Principal As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=" & My.Settings.Server & ";INITIAL CATALOG=" & My.Settings.DB & ";UID=" & My.Settings.user & ";PWD=" & My.Settings.Password & ";workstation id=" & My.Settings.PC & ";packet size=4096")
```